# My code to find shortest path in a graph using bfs is not working for loops

Tags: c, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I had an assignment to write a code for finding shortest path between two nodes in a graph using "BFS". I was giving random inputs and it was working fine until I gave an input with a loop where it did not give the shortest path but looped over that loop.
This is my program, it takes max 9 vertices(0 to 8) as I used 9 as a separator after traversing each node branch

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

int n, m = 0;
int adj[MAX][MAX]; //adjacency matrix, where adj[i][j] = 1, denotes there is an  edge from i to j
int visited[MAX];  //visited[i] can be 0 or 1, 0 : it has not yet printed, 1 : it has been printed
int track[MAX];
void create_graph();
void BF_Traversal();
void BFS();

int queue[MAX], stack[MAX], track[MAX], front = -1, rear = -1, top = -1;
int track_size = 0, stack_size = 0;
void push_queue(int vertex);
int pop_queue();
int isEmpty_queue();
void push_track(int data);
void shortest_path();
void push(int p);
int pop();

int main()
{
    create_graph();  //Create a graph
    BFS();           //Traverse the graph in BFS keeping track of every node visited
    shortest_path(); //Print out the shortest path
    return 0;
}

void BFS()
{
    int v, src, des;

    for (v = 0; v < n; v++)
        visited[v] = 0;

    printf("Enter the source and destination nodes: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &src, &des);
    v = src;

    int i;

    push_queue(v); //A queue is for the normal bfs algorithm
    push_track(9); // this array is to track all the nodes visited

    while (!isEmpty_queue())
    {

        v = pop_queue();
        if(visited[v])
        continue;
        push_track(v);
        visited[v] = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (adj[v][i] == 1)
                push_track(i);
            if (adj[v][i] == 1 && i == des)
                return;
            if (adj[v][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0)
            {
                push_queue(i);
            }
        }
        push_track(9);//I used 9 as a separator after each node traversal, so the max vertices is 9(0-8) 
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void push_queue(int vertex)
{
    if (rear == MAX - 1)
        printf("Queue Overflow\n");
    else
    {
        if (front == -1)
            front = 0;
        rear = rear + 1;
        queue[rear] = vertex;
    }
}

int isEmpty_queue()
{
    if (front == -1 || front > rear)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int pop_queue()
{
    int delete_item;
    if (front == -1 || front > rear)
    {
        printf("Queue Underflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    delete_item = queue[front];
    front = front + 1;
    return delete_item;
}

void push(int p)
{
    top++;
    stack[top] = p;
    stack_size++;
}

int pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}

void push_track(int data)
{
    track[m] = data;
    m++;
    track_size++;
}

void shortest_path()
{
    push(9); //using a stack for arranging the shortest path from the tracking array
    push(track[track_size - 1]);
    int a, i, j, first = 1;
    for (i = track_size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (track[i] == 9 && first == 1)
        {
            a = i + 1;
            push(track[a]);
            first = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if (track[i] == track[a])
        {
            for (j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (track[j] == 9)
                {
                    a = j + 1;
                    push(track[a]);
                    i = i - (i - j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < stack_size - 1; i++)
    {
        int q = pop();
        if (q == 9)
            break;
        printf("%d ", q);
    }
}

void create_graph()
{
    int count, max_edge, origin, destin;

    printf("Enter number of vertices : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    max_edge = n * (n - 1); //assuming each vertex has an edge with remaining (n-1) vertices

    for (count = 1; count <= max_edge; count++)
    {
        printf("Enter edge %d( -1 -1 to quit ) : ", count);
        scanf("%d %d", &origin, &destin);

        if ((origin == -1) && (destin == -1))
            break;

        if (origin >= n || destin >= n || origin < 0 || destin < 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid edge!\n");
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            adj[origin][destin] = 1;
            adj[destin][origin] = 1; // assuming it is a bi-directional graph, we are pushing the reverse edges too.
        }
    }
}
```

What logic should I use to overcome this loop traversal?

Example with correct output,

```
Enter number of vertices : 6
Enter edge 1( -1 -1 to quit ) : 0 1
Enter edge 2( -1 -1 to quit ) : 0 3
Enter edge 3( -1 -1 to quit ) : 1 2
Enter edge 4( -1 -1 to quit ) : 2 3
Enter edge 5( -1 -1 to quit ) : 2 4
Enter edge 6( -1 -1 to quit ) : 3 5
Enter edge 7( -1 -1 to quit ) : -1 -1
Enter the source and destination nodes: 4 5
4 2 3 5
```

Example with incorrect output,

```
Enter number of vertices : 5
Enter edge 1( -1 -1 to quit ) : 0 1
Enter edge 2( -1 -1 to quit ) : 0 2
Enter edge 3( -1 -1 to quit ) : 1 2
Enter edge 4( -1 -1 to quit ) : 2 3
Enter edge 5( -1 -1 to quit ) : 3 4
Enter edge 6( -1 -1 to quit ) : -1 -1
Enter the source and destination nodes: 0 3
0 1 2 3
```

Here above output should be 0 2 3

Comment: The answer has nothing to do with C, but the algorithm. One method is to keep a record of where you have been in your traversal and every time you visit a new node, check to see if you've already visited it. If you have, then don't follow that subpath.  I didn't read through your code, but if you've already taken care of that and you just have a bug in the implementation, then please provide some detail on what you've done to debug it so far.

Comment: Editing your post to add _new_ clarifying information, or to improve formatting is good.  But editing to correct code that has already been addressed in comments or in an answer is not recommended as it causes a moving target for those attempting to help with the problem, and adds confusion to those viewing your question later.  Please refrain from these kinds of edits. I have rolled that edit back to its previous state.

Answer (score 1):

If in the statement:

```
if (track[i] == 9 && first == 1)
```

`tract[i]` is not equal to `9`  then in the statement:

```
if (track[i] == track[a])
```

`a` is not yet initialized.  This results in undefined behavior as `a` can be anything at this point, causing unpredictable results in your loop.

The primary suggestion here is to initialize all your variables.
A close second is to set your compiler to show all warnings, then follow its suggestions.

Comment: `if (track[i] == 9 && first == 1)` this is always true as I use it only to store the last but one variable. But I changed a to a=0

Comment: @Gagankaranth - see my comment under your post about editing your answer.  Stepping through your code with a debugger will help to identify where your logic flow is flawed.